# stringWithFormat and %S problem

Tags: iphone, nsstring, stringwithformat

Here is my code.

```
std::wstring sourceString = L"test\n newline.";
NSString* transformedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", sourceString.c_str()];
```

I intended two strings' contents to be same but transformedString is equivalent to @"t".
How can I fix this with minimal edit?

(I have to use wstring because of unicode issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X/iOS, `wchar_t` is 32 bits wide (i.e. it represents UTF-32 characters, not UTF-16 characters.) `%S` corresponds to a null-terminated `unichar` array, and `unichar` is 16 bits wide, not 32 bits wide, so the character `'t'` appears to `NSString` to have a trailing null character (or leading null character on Big Endian targets) causing the string to be truncated.

To convert to an `NSString`, try:

```
NSString * transformedString = [[NSString alloc]
    initWithBytes: sourceString.c_str()
    length:        sourceString.size() * sizeof(wchar_t)
    encoding:      NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

Note that the above assumes that `wchar_t` holds a UTF-32 value, which is true on Mac OS X and most (all?) *NIXes, but false on Windows (where `wchar_t` is 16 bits, equivalent to `unichar`.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't aware of this method.